# jQuery replace for the new select box only and not the earlier one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I will explain the scenario. I have a website and I am trying to collect "Type of Business" for a members in my website. I display all the existing businesses which have already been entered and then allow the user to choose one of them.  If the user wishes to enter another "Type of Business", I have allowed him to choose, "**OTHER". When he clicks on "**OTHER" a box is displayed in which the user enters his "Type of business" and that gets added.

Now if the user has multiple business, I allow him to "add other". When he clicks on "add other" he is again shown the "Type of Business" including the one which was entered earlier. If the user chooses "**OTHER" again - a box is displayed and when the user enters the another "Type of Business" the same is displayed in the earlier box and the current box.

I want that the new value should be replaced for the new select box only and not the earlier one. How do I make this happen.

**I have writed a small PHP code which does something similar.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function showfield(name){
  if(name=='**OTHER')
 var oth_busi_type = prompt("Please enter a new county", "");
    if (oth_busi_type != null) {
                $(var_1).append('<option selected="selected" value="'+oth_busi_type+'">'+oth_busi_type+'</option>');
    }}

$(document).on('click', '.add-more', function() {
            console.log($('.details:eq(0)').clone());
               $('.details:eq(0)').clone(true).appendTo('.details-parent');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="details-parent">    
<div class="details">    
<table class="extra_table" summary="">
<tr>
    <td class="aligntop bold">*Location:</td>
    <td class="extra_field_input">
         <select class='County' name='County'  id='var_1' onchange='showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)' >             
              <option value="Select County..." selected="selected">Select County...</option>
              <option value="DODGE" >DODGE</option>
              <option value="DOUGLAS" >DOUGLAS</option>
              <option value="LANCASTER" >LANCASTER</option>
              <option value="MADISON" >MADISON</option>
              <option value="**OTHER">**OTHER</option>
         </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td class="aligntop bold extra" style="display:none;">**Enter if **OTHER</td>
    <td class="extra_field_input">
          <input style="display:none;" type="text" size="17" name="Other_County" id="busi_type"  />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="add-more">
    <a href="#">Add more</a> 
</div>

</div>    
</div>    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the updated code below

i also created

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready (function (e){
    var details = $('.details:eq(0)').clone(true);
    $(document).on ('change', '.County', function (e){
        if ($(this).val() =='**OTHER'){
            var oth_busi_type = prompt("Please enter a new county", "");
        }

        if (oth_busi_type != null) {
            $(this).append('<option selected="selected" value="'+oth_busi_type+'">'+oth_busi_type+'</option>');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.add-more', function() {
        console.log($('.details:eq(0)').clone());
        $(details).clone(true).appendTo('.details-parent');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="details-parent">
    <div class="details">
        <table class="extra_table" summary="">
            <tr>
                <td class="aligntop bold">*Location:</td>
                <td class="extra_field_input">
                     <select class='County' name='County'  id='var_1' >
                          <option value="Select County..." selected="selected">Select County...</option>
                          <option value="DODGE" >DODGE</option>
                          <option value="DOUGLAS" >DOUGLAS</option>
                          <option value="LANCASTER" >LANCASTER</option>
                          <option value="MADISON" >MADISON</option>
                          <option value="**OTHER">**OTHER</option>
                     </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="aligntop bold extra" style="display:none;">**Enter if **OTHER</td>
                <td class="extra_field_input">
                      <input style="display:none;" type="text" size="17" name="Other_County" id="busi_type"  />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="add-more">
            <a href="#">Add more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from this line of code:

```
$(var_1).append('<option selected="selected" value="'+oth_busi_type+'">'+oth_busi_type+'</option>');
```

`//I assure that $(var_1) is just for ex.. and you've done $('#var_1') in your actual code` 
Here `var_1` is the id so you're essentially changing the values of all the selects to that set to the last one..

The easy fix here would `onchange` event even pass `this` as param and change the value of only that select.

So in your `html`:

```
//passing additional param this
<select class='County' name='County'  id='var_1' onchange='showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,this)' >
```

and in your `js`:

```
//ref is this
function showfield(name,ref){
  if(name=='**OTHER')
 var oth_busi_type = prompt("Please enter a new county", "");
    if (oth_busi_type != null) {
//use ref instead of var_1
                $(ref).append('<option selected="selected" value="'+oth_busi_type+'">'+oth_busi_type+'</option>');
    }}
```